# Inconveniences with maintaining Stack Frames and Symbol Tables Separately

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter, stack-frame, symbol-table

**Intoduction**
I'm creating a statically typed language where all variables are treated as static global variables. Therefore the amount of memory required is known at compile time (similar to how Fortran 66 works). I've observed that the structure of the stack frames are equivalent to the structure of the symbol tables. The only difference is, is that symbol tables contain the type of a symbol while stack frames contain the value of a variable.

[image]

**Inconveniences** This has led to a "doubling" up of efforts to make sure that these two tables are equivalent. I need to make sure that they generate in the same way, that AST nodes are decorated with references to a symbol table/stack frame that represent the same scope. A more notable task is the implementation of built in variables/methods. Defining and initialising a built-in requires me to first define their type in a symbol table, and then give it's value in a stack frame. On top of that, I also have namespaces which are represented by a symbol table and stack frame. Thus I need to make sure that the links to these namespaces are identical in both table formats.

To summarise, managing two different table types is inconvenient and prone to making silly mistakes.

**Solutions?** Is what I'm describing problems that other languages experience? If so, how do they get around this problem? I was thinking about merging the stack frame and symbol table together during the semantic analysis phase, but I'm fearful that I'm overlooking something or that this approach may cause some problems down the road. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say "no *new* stack frames are created at run time", which is confusing to me. Generally *all* stack frames are created at run time. If your language doesn't allow recursion (allowing you to store local variables/parameters and return addresses globally), you don't need a stack at all, so there should be 0 stack frames - not some fixed number of them that are created at compile time.

Comment: @sepp2k I generate the stack frames prior to the actual code generation so I confusingly referred to this as compile time, but yes it technically is run time so I'll change that - thanks for pointing it out. And in regards to your second point, I need to store the values of variables somewhere though, so how can I go about not using any stack frames at all?

Comment: @sepp2k And yes, recursion is not allowed.

Comment: "I generate the stack frames prior to the actual code generation" I have no idea what that means. Stack frames are created by moving the stack pointer, which obviously happens when the code is run (i.e. *after* code generation). Do you mean you generate the code that increases the stack pointer before code generation (shouldn't it be during)?

Comment: "And in regards to your second point, I need to store the values of variables somewhere though, so how can I go about not using any stack frames at all?" Global variables aren't stored on the stack, they're stored at fixed memory addresses. In a language without recursion, you can do the same thing with local variables and return addresses, i.e. assign them a fixed address (not relative to the stack pointer) during semantic analysis.

Comment: @sepp2k Thank you for the information. Doing some more research with what you've told me has led me to the conclusion that I don't need stack frames at all for my language (since everything is treated as static data). I'm going with the approach of assigning a variable a fixed address during semantic analysis and then binding that symbol information to the AST to resolve the location during code generation.